# How to load dependant tableViewCell API data properly?

Tags: ios, json, uitableview, swift

I've been working on a `UITableView` that makes 2 API calls for every cell for a while now. It's been working fine. However today I encountered a massive issue. For the first time, there were more cells on the screen than there was loaded cells.

So when I scrolled down my tableView the screen froze for several seconds because it hadn't loaded the last cell.

A problem I've been having trying to load this data properly. Is that my second API call for each cell depends on the first one.

Here's how it's currently set up:

my `tableView`:

```
// #tableView
    tableView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
    tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.formulaWhiteColor()
    tableView.frame         =   CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0)
    tableView.delegate      =   self
    tableView.dataSource    =   self
    self.tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRectZero)
    self.tableView.separatorColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    tableView.registerClass(mySuggestionsCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "com.Formula.mySuggestionsCell")
    tableView.addSubview(refreshControl)
    self.view.addSubview(tableView)
```

When my view Appears I run this function:

```
func loadSuggestions() {
    DNService.suggestionsForSection() { (JSON) -> () in
        self.suggestions = JSON["actionable"]
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
    }
}
```

(My DNSService is a struct using Alomafire)

```
struct DNService {

static func suggestionsForSection(response: (JSON) -> ()) {
    let urlString = suggestionsURL
    Alamofire.request(.GET, urlString).responseJSON { (_, _, data, _) -> Void in
        let suggestions = JSON(data ?? [])
        response(suggestions)
    }
}
}
```

From there I start setting up the cells:

Number of rows:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return suggestions.count
}
```

And the actual configuration:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("com.Formula.mySuggestionsCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! mySuggestionsCell
    let suggestion = suggestions[indexPath.row]
    cell.configureWithSuggestion(suggestion)
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None
    return cell
}
```

The rest is currently taking place in my UITableViewCell which I'm pretty sure is where I'm going completely wrong in how I'm doing this.

```
func configureWithSuggestion(suggestion: JSON) {
    tickerString = suggestion["ticker"].string!
    tickerLabel.text = tickerString

    // I'm setting up other things like above, but cut them out as they aren't relevant.

    var quoteAPI = NSURL(string: "http://dev.markitondemand.com/Api/v2/Quote/json?symbol=\(tickerString)")
    // This is the API that depends on data from the first API.
    // This is being called for every cell that's being configured...

    var request = NSURLRequest(URL: quoteAPI!)
    var data = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: nil, error: nil)
    if data != nil {
        var quote = JSON(data: data!)
        lastPrice = quote["LastPrice"]
        // Again calling more data than just this.
    }
    lastPriceLabel.text = lastPrice
    // I'm also setting up and animating some charts here.
}
```

How do I best go about retrieving and setting up this API data, when one of the calls depends on the first one?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up making a coreData entity for the data.

Then when the view loads, I call the first api, loop through it, save it to coreData and in the loop I can use the variable to call the second api as well.

Then when I'm loading my cells from coreData instead of making api calls when scrolling down, there's no problem with loading time.